# How to use videojs with a jekyll powered site

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, jekyll, video-player

Trying to create a custom skinned video player on this page.
http://turbosaurusrex.github.io/keets/
I'd like to hide every element except the play button. I've linked video.js and the css file but it doesn't seem like it's working?

I threw the cdn right after the body tag:

```
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

The video player returns the browser's native player. No change I make to the css does anything. Is this a jekyll thing I've overlooked, am I stupid or what? I don't know. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `id` attribute and `data-setup` for each video.

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md#step-2-add-an-html5-video-tag-to-your-page

```
<video autoplay="" controls="" loop="" poster="/video/keets/keet1.jpg" id="firstvid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin col-xs-12" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="/video/keets/keet1.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/video/keets/keet1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```